# Is it possible to track the actual driven distance with the car in an Flutter App with Google Maps API?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, tracking

So basically, I want to have a button where I can begin the tracking, and when I click the second time, the driven route should be displayed on the map and the driven distance (in kilometres) should be displayed.

I searched up the Internet but found no solution on that.

I would be happy if anyone could help me, thanks.

Comment: You'll need to specify the recording interval and accuracy to help you decide what the number might be.  The "straight as the crow flies" distance will be trivial, but any kind of curve measurement will be quickly problematic.  Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox

Comment: This maps toolkit https://pub.dev/packages/maps_toolkit allows you to compute distances between points.  This plus the "recording of points" from current location can give an _approximation_ of total distance traveled over time.  Also available in github: https://github.com/kb0/maps_toolkit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For as far as I'm concerned this can not be achieved via a Google Maps API.

Like Andy replied in a comment on your question, you can keep track of the coordinates from the Geolocator package (https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) and compute the distance between each sequential point (Maps Toolkit provides these functions: https://pub.dev/packages/maps_toolkit).
Add these up and you have an approximation of the distance. How more often you keep track of the location, how more accurate it will be.

Keep in mind: if you track based on time, the approximation may be less accurate due the (higher) speed of the device that's travelling. I'd suggest you adjust the interval of point-tracking based on the speed.

Comment: For people viewing this post from today on, following this article could make life a lot easier: https://medium.com/@ahmedijaz0007/google-maps-in-flutter-2023-660f9ef5f076